# how to multiply each row of a tensor to the rest of rows element wise in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor like this:

```
tf_docs = tf.constant([[0, 2, 1],
                       [1, 2, 2],
                       [2, 1, 3],
                       [5, 2, 2]], dtype=tf.int32)
```

I need to multiply each row by rest of the rows, element wise and then sum up result.

When done with first row, we will do with second row and rest of the rows and...

So the result will be like this: It will be `4*4` because we have 4 rows

```
result_tf =[[0,  6,  5, 6 ],
            [6,  0, 10, 13],
            [5, 10,  3, 18],
            [6,  13, 18, 0]]
```

Let me explain each element in `result_tf` (the matrix is symmetrical.

first row:

```
0*1 + 2*2 + 1*2 = 6
0*2 + 2*1 + 1*3 = 5
0*5 + 2*2 + 1*2 = 6
```

Second row:

```
1*2 + 2*1 + 2*3 = 10
1*5 + 2*2 + 2*2 = 13
```

third row:

```
2*5 + 1*2 + 3*2 = 18
```

These are how I formed the upper side of the matrix.

then the values in the diag are:

`(0,0)` has not `co-occurred` in any column so `0`

`(1,1)` has not `co-occurred` in any column so `0`

`(2,2)` has `co-occurred 2` time in second column and `1 time` third column so `3`

`(3,3)` has not co-occurred in any column so `0`

I feel this needs more creativity to solve than knowing techniques. (Literally here I am computing the co-occurrence over the same matrix if you are aware of the concept of co-occurrence)

What I have done:

I can do this easily using for loop. But I need to be done with the tensorflow operation.and I could not find anything similar to this problem.
I was also thinking use gather to get specified rows each time and concat them. But this way is not dynamic and my rows and columns are larger than this so this solution will not be feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf_docs = tf.constant([[0, 2, 1],
                       [1, 2, 2],
                       [2, 1, 3],
                       [5, 2, 2]], dtype=tf.int32)

# Non-diagonal elements
nondiag = tf.matmul(tf_docs, tf_docs, transpose_b=True)
# Compute diagonal
r = tf.range(tf.shape(tf_docs, out_type=tf_docs.dtype)[0])
# Compare each index against each value
cmp = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(tf_docs, axis=-1), r)
# Count appearances of each index in each column
count = tf.math.count_nonzero(cmp, axis=0, dtype=tf_docs.dtype)
# Sum number of appearances over one
diag = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(count - 1, 0), axis=0)
# Set diagonal elements
result_tf = tf.linalg.set_diag(nondiag, diag)
print(result_tf.numpy())
# [[ 0  6  5  6]
#  [ 6  0 10 13]
#  [ 5 10  3 18]
#  [ 6 13 18  0]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and you are AWESOME. This is very kind of you being patient and answering my question. I usually review the answer so that next time I would be able to solve myself. I still have not got the skill in tensorflow. I understand your solution (except how you come up with `cmp` part) but when new questions come up I cant solve it :| which I think it takes time and more practice maybe:), I almost there to finish this project :)

Comment: @sariii Glad it helped. The `cmp` tensor is a 3D tensor such that `cmp[i, j, k]` is `True` if `tf_docs[i, j]` is `k` and `False` otherwise. It's an all-to-all comparison, which is not super efficient, but hopefully it may work for you. I'm sure you will be getting better with TF every day, and I appreciate your effort making the question very clear, these are difficult problems for anyone, experienced or not. Do not hesitate to keep asking as much as needed, that's the point of SO.

Comment: Do you mind having a look at my question here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60910269/how-to-construct-a-matrix-that-contains-all-pairs-of-rows-of-a-matrix-in-tensorf . someone already has answered and answer is kind of correct but the shape is not. Thanks again :)