# how to keep the values of tensors in each epoch in one layer and pass it to Next epoch in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras-layer

I have a general question.

I am developing a new layer to incorporate into an autoencoder. To be more specific, the layer is something like the `KCompetitive` class over [here](https://github.com/hugochan/KATE/blob/master/autoencoder/utils/keras_utils.py). What I want is that I need to save the output of this layer in a variable let's call it `previous_mat_values`, and then pass it to that same layer in the next epoch as well.

To put it another way, I want to be able to save the output of this layer of `epoch 1` in one variable, and then in `epoch 2`, again use that same matrix.

So the question arises what would be the values of this matrix in the first epoch because it does not have the output of that layer yet. We can initialize an array with the same shape of the weight matrix but with values of `0` I will do like this.

```
previous_mat_values = tf.zeros_like(weight_tensor)
```

So the steps are like this:

1. In the first epoch, `previous_mat_values` and `weight_mat` will pass to the layer

   1.a at the end of the function of that layer, the final value of which we call it `modified_weight_mat` will save into the `previous_mat_values`

   `previous_mat_values = modified_weight_mat`
2. In the second epoch, `previous_mat_values` and `weight_mat` will pass to the layer, however, `previous_mat_values` has the values saved in the first epoch.

I don't have any problem passing `weight_mat` and doing stuff related to that. The only issue here is that how we can save the values of `previous_mat_values` in each epoch and pass it to the next epoch.

I was thinking to create a global tensor variable in the `class of that layer` and initialize it with zero, but I don't think it will help to keep the values of the previous epoch into the second epoch.

Do you have any idea how can I implement this?

Please let me know if my explanations are not clear.

**Update 1:**

This is the implementation of the layer:

```
class KCompetitive(Layer):
    '''Applies K-Competitive layer.
    # Arguments
    '''
    def __init__(self, topk, ctype, **kwargs):
        self.topk = topk
        self.ctype = ctype
        self.uses_learning_phase = True
        self.supports_masking = True
        super(KCompetitive, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        if self.ctype == 'ksparse':
            return K.in_train_phase(self.kSparse(x, self.topk), x)
        elif self.ctype == 'kcomp':
            return K.in_train_phase(self.k_comp_tanh(x, self.topk), x)
        else:
            warnings.warn("Unknown ctype, using no competition.")
            return x

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'topk': self.topk, 'ctype': self.ctype}
        base_config = super(KCompetitive, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def k_comp_tanh(self, x, topk, factor=6.26):
        ###Some modification on x so now the x becomes 
        x= x+1
        res = x
        return res
```

**Update 2**

For more clarification I will add this:

**sample 1 of data:**

```
x_prev = zero
mask = tf.greate(x, x_prev)   # x here related to sample 1
x_modified = x[mask]
x_prev = x_modified
```

**Sample 2 of data:**

```
mask = tf.greater(x, x_prev)   # x here related to sample 2  and 
x_prev is from previous sample
x_modified = x[mask]
x_prev = x_modified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can have a variable in your layer that simply gets updated with the previous value of another variable on each training step, something along these lines:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                initializer='random_normal',
                                trainable=self.trainable,
                                name='W')
        self.w_prev = self.add_weight(shape=self.w.shape,
                                      initializer='zeros',
                                      trainable=False,
                                      name='W_prev')

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        # Only update value of w_prev on training steps
        deps = []
        if training:
            deps.append(self.w_prev.assign(self.w))
        with tf.control_dependencies(deps):
            return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w)
```

Here is a usage example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.random.set_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
# Make a random linear problem
x = np.random.rand(50, 3)
y = x @ np.random.rand(3, 2)
# Make model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
my_layer = MyLayer(2, input_shape=(3,))
model.add(my_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='mse')
# Train
cbk = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(
    on_batch_begin=lambda batch, logs: (tf.print('batch:', batch),
                                        tf.print('w_prev:', my_layer.w_prev, sep='\n'),
                                        tf.print('w:', my_layer.w, sep='\n')))
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=10, epochs=1, verbose=0, callbacks=[cbk])
```

Output:

```
batch: 0
w_prev:
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
w:
[[0.0755531341 0.0211461019]
 [-0.0209847465 -0.0518018603]
 [-0.0618413948 0.0235136505]]
batch: 1
w_prev:
[[0.0755531341 0.0211461019]
 [-0.0209847465 -0.0518018603]
 [-0.0618413948 0.0235136505]]
w:
[[0.0770048052 0.0292659812]
 [-0.0199236758 -0.04635958]
 [-0.060054455 0.0332755931]]
batch: 2
w_prev:
[[0.0770048052 0.0292659812]
 [-0.0199236758 -0.04635958]
 [-0.060054455 0.0332755931]]
w:
[[0.0780589 0.0353098139]
 [-0.0189863108 -0.0414136574]
 [-0.0590113513 0.0387929156]]
batch: 3
w_prev:
[[0.0780589 0.0353098139]
 [-0.0189863108 -0.0414136574]
 [-0.0590113513 0.0387929156]]
w:
[[0.0793346688 0.042034667]
 [-0.0173048507 -0.0330933407]
 [-0.0573575757 0.0470812619]]
batch: 4
w_prev:
[[0.0793346688 0.042034667]
 [-0.0173048507 -0.0330933407]
 [-0.0573575757 0.0470812619]]
w:
[[0.0805450454 0.0485667922]
 [-0.0159637 -0.0261840075]
 [-0.0563304275 0.052557759]]
```

---

EDIT: I'm still not 100% sure how exactly you need this to work, but here is something that might work for you:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class KCompetitive(Layer):
    '''Applies K-Competitive layer.
    # Arguments
    '''
    def __init__(self, topk, ctype, **kwargs):
        self.topk = topk
        self.ctype = ctype
        self.uses_learning_phase = True
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.x_prev = None
        super(KCompetitive, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        if self.ctype == 'ksparse':
            return K.in_train_phase(self.kSparse(x, self.topk), x)
        elif self.ctype == 'kcomp':
            return K.in_train_phase(self.k_comp_tanh(x, self.topk), x)
        else:
            warnings.warn("Unknown ctype, using no competition.")
            return x

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'topk': self.topk, 'ctype': self.ctype}
        base_config = super(KCompetitive, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def k_comp_tanh(self, x, topk, factor=6.26):
        if self.x_prev is None:
            self.x_prev = self.add_weight(shape=x.shape,
                                          initializer='zeros',
                                          trainable=False,
                                          name='X_prev')
        ###Some modification on x so now the x becomes 
        x_modified = self.x_prev.assign(x + 1)
        return x_modified
```

Here is an example of usage:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
# Make model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(batch_shape=(3, 4)))
my_layer = KCompetitive(2, 'kcomp')
print(my_layer.x_prev)
# None
model.add(my_layer)
# The variable gets created after it is added to a model
print(my_layer.x_prev)
# <tf.Variable 'k_competitive/X_prev:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='mse')

# "Train"
x = tf.zeros((3, 4))
cbk = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(
    on_epoch_begin=lambda batch, logs:
        tf.print('initial x_prev:', my_layer.x_prev, sep='\n'),
    on_epoch_end=lambda batch, logs:
        tf.print('final x_prev:', my_layer.x_prev, sep='\n'),)
model.fit(x, x, epochs=1, verbose=0, callbacks=[cbk])
# initial x_prev:
# [[0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]]
# final x_prev:
# [[1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213382/discussion-on-answer-by-jdehesa-how-to-keep-the-values-of-tensors-in-each-epoch).

Comment: @jdehesa It's me again back :). I got a good results and for that I appreciate all your help. if my paper gets accepted I will share it with you :). The idea behind it is cool but I'm not sure I can present it formally very well. I need to visualize some of the values of the operation I have. Would you mind have a look at my question here  please https://stackoverflow.com/users/7934786/sariii

Comment: @sariii Glad to know you're making progress, it would be very interesting to see any publication you get out of it, even though it's not exactly the domain I work on. I will have a look at your question and let you know if I can help.